# Refresh js function after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh, jquery-selectbox

I'm using this jquery plugin https://web.archive.org/web/20151007012231/http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/

and I need to refresh it after an ajax call, I've already tried "selectbox.refresh()" and just "selectbox()" but nothing worked.

Any idea how to?

Comment: Please provide the code you already have.. So we can try to understand what needs fixing

Comment: I will try something before, thank u!

Answer (score 0):

When I visit selectbox API official page, there is not mehtod `.refresh()`.
But instead, you can use `.selectbox("detach")`.

> Remove the selectbox functionality completely. This will return the
>   element back to its pre-init state.

Then after destroying it, you can re-instanciate it!

Good luck

Comment: thanks man, I will try and return back here to tell if it worked.